# Как можно создать "ярлыков" приложения в меню приложения и главном экране

Tags: android, kotlin

Как можно организовать создание нескольких "ярлыков" приложения с определёнными критериями запуска который может быть и на главном экране и в меню приложения.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts

Comment: @YuraIvanov а создание в меню приложений ярлык на это приложение возможно? То есть один "главный" само приложение, а второе со специальным запуском для открытия другой части или разделения одного приложения.

Comment: Читайте доки, пробуйте. Можно.